# How to modify array element within javascript object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json

I am writing my code in `NodeJS` and have a object which looks as below.

```js
const jsonData=
{
    "description": "description",
    "hosts": [
        "host1",
        "host2",
        "host3"
    ]
}
```

I want to delete all `host` elements execpt the first one.

Desired Output:

```js
const jsonData=
{
    "description": "description",
    "hosts": [
        "host1"
    ]
}
```

And, the remaining elements should be moved to another variable.

```js
const hostelementsExceptFirst = [ "host2", "host3" ];
```

I am performing the following operation but it is not giving desired output.

```js
delete jsonData['hosts'];
```

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to mutate the array, you can use `splice`..

eg..

```js
const jsonData =
{
    "description": "description",
    "hosts": [
        "host1", "host2", "host3"
    ]
}

const hostelementsExceptFirst = jsonData.hosts.splice(1);

console.log(jsonData);
console.log(hostelementsExceptFirst);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Array.slice() to take a section of an array, and just reassign the hosts value afterwards.

```js
const jsonData =
{
    "description": "description",
    "hosts": [
        "host1", "host2", "host3"
    ]
}

const remainers = jsonData.hosts.slice(1);
jsonData.hosts = [jsonData.hosts[0]];

console.log(jsonData);
console.log(remainers);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const [firstValue, ...othersValues] = jsonData.hosts;
```

firstValue will be host1, and othersValues will be array with others

Comment: This is a good start but doesn't alter the `jsonData.hosts` at all